# Replace expected at least 2 arguments got 1 error

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Hello I got some stuck in my code and I tried but I still don't know how to fix it. Here it's my code.

```
def staff_info (name):
  print ("So you are " + name + ", years old. ")
name = input ("Type your name: ")
confirm_info = input ("So you have " + name + ". Confirm that? (Yes/No) ")
  if confirm_info == "Yes":
    print ("Okay so I have few more question for you. ")
  else:
    confirm_info == "No"
    change_info = input ("So what do you want to change? ")
    if change_info == "name":
        name_change = input ("Type the name you want to change: ")
        name = name.replace (name_change) #error here
       ...
    else: 
       ...
print ("So you are " + name + ", " + age + " years old. You have over " + result_experience1 + " with code.")
```

If you could explain it and give me a command to solve it, I'd appreciate it. My adventure with Python beginning last week from now. Thanks you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The`replace` method takes two mandatory parameters:

1. The `substring` you want to replace
2. The new value

So, change this

```py
name = name.replace (name_change)
```

to

```py
 name = name.replace(name, name_change)
```

More [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_replace.htm)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
def staff_info(name):
    print("So you are " + name + ", years old. ")
    name = input("Type your name: ")
    confirm_info = input("So you have " + name + ". Confirm that? (Yes/No) ")
    if confirm_info == "Yes":
        print("Okay so I have few more question for you. ")
    elif confirm_info == "No":
        change_info = input("So what do you want to change? ")
        if change_info != name:
            name_change = input("Type the name you want to change: ")
            new_name = name_change.replace(name, name_change)
            print("New Name = ", new_name)
        else:
            print("...")
```

Answer (score 0):

here is what i used to rename the files

```
import os

path=r''

def startRename():
    files=os.listdir(path)
    count=1
    for file in files:
       os.rename(f"{path}\{file}",f"{path}\{count}.wav")
       count+=1

startRename()
```

Comment: why rename code? the question is about replace.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34571014)